# How can I draw this table in LaTeX?

Tags: tables, multirow, multicolumn

How can I draw this table in LaTeX ?

[image]

Here is my MWE:

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 & & &  A & B & C & D \\
\hline
 & & Durée & \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Taxe[DA/Km$^{2}$]} \\
\hline
\multirow{3}*{Période de recherche} & Phase initiale & 3 ans & 4000 & 4800 & 6000 & 8000 \\
\cline{2-7}
 & 2$^{me}$phase & 2 ans & 6000 & 8000 & 10000 & 12000 \\
\cline{2-7}
 & 3$^{me}$phase & 2 ans & 8000 & 12000 & 14000 & 16000 \\
 \hline
 \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Période de rétention + période exceptionnelle} &  0 ans & 400000 & 560000 & 720000 & 800000 \\
 \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Période d’exploitation} & 25 ans & 16000 & 24000 & 28000 & 32000 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Tarif de la taxe superficiaire}
\label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
```

I get this:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

- To remove a horizontal line, use `\cline{3-7}` instead of `\hline`.
- To remove a vertical line, use `\multicolumn{2}{c|}{}` and specify only the desired vertical lines.
- Alter `\extrarowheight` (from the `array` package) to add some space to each row, so it looks nicer.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\cline{4-7}
\multicolumn{3}{c|}{} &  A & B & C & D \\
\cline{3-7}
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & Durée & \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Taxe[DA/Km$^{2}$]} \\
\hline
\multirow{3}*{Période de recherche} & Phase initiale & 3 ans & 4000 & 4800 & 6000 & 8000 \\
\cline{2-7}
& 2$^{me}$phase & 2 ans & 6000 & 8000 & 10000 & 12000 \\
\cline{2-7}
& 3$^{me}$phase & 2 ans & 8000 & 12000 & 14000 & 16000 \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Période de rétention + période exceptionnelle} &  0 ans & 400000 & 560000 & 720000 & 800000 \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Période d’exploitation} & 25 ans & 16000 & 24000 & 28000 & 32000 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Tarif de la taxe superficiaire}
\label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe you could add a bit extra row height (like `\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}`) to make it look a bit better.

Comment: I'll try this too, thank you for the trick :)

Answer (score 5):

I would like to suggest that you give your table a much more open "look", mainly by getting rid of all vertical lines and most horizontal lines. For the few remaining horizontal lines, don't use `\hline` and `\cline`. Insetead, use the well-spaced lines provided by the `booktabs` package: `\toprule`; `\bottomrule`,  `\midrule`, `\cmidrule`, and `addlinespace`. (The last macro adds "just" whitespace. As a divider, whitespace can be every bit as effective as an actual, visible line.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % choose page dimensions

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\sisetup{group-digits=false,per-mode=symbol}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} ll r *{4}{S[table-format=6.0]} @{}}
\toprule
 & & & {A} & {B} & {C} & {D} \\
\cmidrule(l){4-7}
 & & Durée & \multicolumn{4}{c@{}}{Taxe [\si{DA\per\kilo\meter\squared}]} \\
\midrule
Période de recherche & Phase initiale & 3 ans & 4000 & 4800 & 6000 & 8000 \\
%\cline{2-7}
 & 2\textsuperscript{me} phase & 2 ans & 6000 & 8000 & 10000 & 12000 \\
 & 3\textsuperscript{me} phase & 2 ans & 8000 & 12000 & 14000 & 16000 \\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Période de rétention \& période exceptionnelle} 
                               &  0 ans & 400000 & 560000 & 720000 & 800000 \\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Période d'exploitation} 
                               & 25 ans & 16000 & 24000 & 28000 & 32000 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Tarif de la taxe superficiaire}
\label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is indeed more beautiful to look, and it's very clear thank you :)